Return Entity for static reference tables via mapstruct
3 tables A,B and a reference table status having column status_code which fetches details like description and type. Using Springboot 3.2.5 and JPA and
<mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</mapstruct.version>
<lombok-mapstruct-binding>0.2.0</lombok-mapstruct-binding>

Defined mapper for A and B using AEntity and BEntity with their respective DTO's. Each of these classes contain status field which is a FK from status table. How to define the status mapper such that the mapper returns the Entity which is present in the repository for the given status code in the DTO for status object?
As suggested by @Alex, I wrote it as an abstract class like this -
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class StatusTypeMapper {
    @Autowired
    private StatusTypeRepository StatusTypeRepository;
    StatusTypeMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(StatusTypeMapper.class);

    StatusType toEntity(StatusTypeDTO StatusTypeDTO){
        return StatusTypeRepository.findById(StatusTypeDTO.getStatusCode()).get();
    }
} 

and then after compiling I get the below error -
StatusTypeMapperImpl.<init>(StatusTypeMapperImpl.java:12)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor57.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.doGetMapper(Mappers.java:85)
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:69)
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:58)
    at myPackage.mapper.StatusTypeMapper.<init>(StatusTypeMapper.java:15)
    at myPackage.mapper.StatusTypeMapperImpl.<init>(StatusTypeMapperImpl.java:12)

Since I am already doing the mapping using mapstruct, I was hoping it to allow me to map the DTO to Enity already present in database in some way..Else I need to fetch it again in my Service layer and it would be rework for nested entities, where this status_code appears multiple times in my parent object

What should return this mapper if Entity not present in repository for given status code?

@Alex Thanks for looking into it, It should return IntegrityVoilationException if the entity is not found as it would if we did a JPARepository findById(status_code). The challenge I faced while making a default method use a JPARepository was that interface could not autowire it, and on maven-compile, its implementation went blank

Write mapper as abstract class. It allows you to autowire the repository

@Alex updated question with edits of trial of the suggestion

If you have service layer you should use repository in service layer only, not in mapper from architectural point of view. Implement the desired method obtaining entity from dto in service layer. Use cash for entities found from database to prevent going to database second time I can provide an example if you need it

Yes, we do have the architectural setup to have an intermediary service layer, I wanted to avoid the rework of first creating a dto using the status code from request json and then using mapper to convert to an entity (for reference tables, its like creating a new object placeholder) whereas in service layer I would now need to findById using the entity placeholder object that mapstruct created. Hence was thinking if it could be one-shot for reference tables, which dont change that often. However abstract class errored out. Thanks.Caching example most welcome

Instead of using repository in mapper we can move the method
public StatusType toEntity(StatusTypeDTO StatusTypeDTO){
        return StatusTypeRepository.findById(StatusTypeDTO.getStatusCode()).get();
    }

to service layer. Lets rewrite it to use cache:
@Service
public StatusTypeService {

  @Autowired 
  StatusTypeRepository statusTypeRepository;


  @Cacheable("status_code")
  public StatusType findStatusTypeById(Long id) {
    return statusTypeRepository.findById(id);
  }

  public StatusType toEntity(StatusTypeDTO StatusTypeDTO) {
    return findStatusTypeById(statusTypeDTO.getStatusType.get());
  }

}


where the first function will find the entity in database by id and store it in the cache named "status_code" That is similar to store it in the map
Map <Long, StatusCodeEntity> status_code;

The second function use the first, so when entity requested second time it will be found in cache
Note, in example I use Long as StatusEntity ID type but it might be different in your case

one more doubt-using this statusTypeRepository.findById(id).get() to get back reference table entity but not able to catch the integrityconstraintexception then, not sure how to specifically catch exceptions and map them to custom exceptions, for eg, need to map SQLState: 23000 to custom exception.

There are several methods to catch and process exception besides try-catch. See the complete guide at https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-exception-handling/ I use @ControllerAdvice from there and also @Aspect described at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/referenhttps://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop.htmlce/core/aop.html

Sorry, the true reference for aspects is https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop.html

thanks @Alex will have a look at these.

A mapper could also be defined in the form of an abstract class instead of an interface and implement the custom methods directly in the mapper class. In this case MapStruct will generate an extension of the abstract class with implementations of all abstract methods, see https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#sub-class-mappings
So the rough code may be
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring)
public abstract class EntityToModelMapper {

  @Autowired EntityRepository entityRepository;

  @Mapping(target = "status", expression = "java(map(arg))")
  public abstract Model convert(Entity arg);

  StatusType map(Entity entity) {
    // use repository here and return status or throw exception
  }
}


Or you keep it an interface and either define a default method or a static one (which I find is more appropriate but clutters the annotation expression too much because it needs to use the fully qualified class name for the method).

@daniu one of requirements is using repository bean as autowired. As was said interface does not allow it

Tried the abstract class and updated the issue I ran into above, my objective primarily is to use the status code present in a json field in request body and map it to the status code entity which appears in the field of my parent object when I save it as a single entity.
